# Android Action Bar Tabs and Menu Items

Tags: android

I am using a action bar. I have menu items on that. I have set the property on it as

```
android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText"
```

So it's working in Potrait and landscape really well. On one page I have Tabs, it's not recognizing tabs and overwriting the tabs. What I would like to do is, in Potarit just show tabs and all menu in drop down. In Landscape show tabs and as many menu items possible on action bar.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Have a `res/menu/options.xml` and a `res/values-land/options.xml` to distinguish the cases. Or, if the rule really is not portrait vs. landscape but a minimum screen width, use `res/menu/options.xml` and `res/menu-wNNNdp/options.xml`, where `NNN` is the minimum width in `dp` for when you want to use some other approach for your menu.